# differential equation (proof)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, derivatives

Consider on $(0,+\infty)$ the differential equation
\begin{align}
\label{eq}
x^2y''(x)+xy'(x)+y(x)=10\ . \quad\quad(1)
\end{align}
For a twice derivable function $y:(0,+\infty)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, define $u:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ as
\begin{align}
u(t)=y\left(e^t\right).
\end{align}
Show that $y$ solves $(1)$ if and only if the corresponding $u$ satisfies
\begin{align}
u''(t)+u(t)=10\ .
\end{align}

Do I just replace $y$ with $u$ in the equation and then try to solve it?

Comment: This might be wrong, the auxillary/characteristic polynomial is $0=r(r-1)+2r+1=r^2+r+1$, not $r^2+1$ alone.

Comment: Plus the diff equation $(1)$ is not homogeneous.

Comment: there was a mistake in the question, should be right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$x^2y''(x)+xy'(x)+y(x)=10 \quad\quad(1)$$
This is Cauchy-Euler's differential equation. Change variable $x=e^t$:
$$y'_x=\dfrac {dy}{dt}\dfrac {dt}{dx}=e^{-t}y'_t$$
$$y''_x=(-e^{-t}y'_t+e^{-t}y''_t)e^{-t}$$
$$y''_x=(y''_t-y'_t)e^{-2t}$$
The equation becomes:
$$-y'_t+y''_t+y'_t+y_t=10$$
$$y''_t++y_t=10$$

Comment: hi, thanks for the response, there a was a small mistake in both equations, in the first one i replaced $2xy'$ with $xy'$ and in the second equation i replaced $0$ with $10$.

Comment: Oh I see. No Problem . @BobMartin I have corrected my answer.